# Extracting the median and confidence intervals from several variables into a separate table in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame in R which looks like this:

```
ID       A       B     C      D
1  31.63237      6     24    10.6
2       NA      1     62    10.4
3 18.04803      5      2     7.9
3 26.73194     24     19     7.6
```

How can i extract only the median and 95% confidence intervals into a separate table?
This is my desired output

```
    A       B     C       D
```

Median 26.73201 16     35     8.35

5%    18.48319 19.39076  18.61792
95%   40.39744 39.89518  41.60440

Comment: `Q <- sapply(df[-1], quantile, probs=c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975), na.rm=TRUE)` ... then after `Q[-2,] ## CI` for the 95% confidence intervals.

Comment: What is your desired output? ... edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53192141/edit

Comment: how can I include a row displaying the median of the variables into this equation?

Comment: the second row of `Q` are the medians. `Q[2, ]`. For your output you can do `Q[c(2, 1, 3), ]` ... and (if you want) set the rownames.

Comment: Your desired output is not konsistent with your data: 5%- and 95%-percentile have only three numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"ID       A       B     C      D
1  31.63237      6     24    10.6
2       NA      1     62    10.4
3 18.04803      5      2     7.9
3 26.73194     24     19     7.6")

Q <- sapply(df[-1], quantile, probs=c(0.5, 0.05, 0.95), na.rm=TRUE)
Q
# > Q
#            A    B     C      D
# 50% 26.73194  5.5 21.50  9.150
# 5%  18.91642  1.6  4.55  7.645
# 95% 31.14233 21.3 56.30 10.570
```

The range from the 5%-percentile to the 95%-percentile is a 90%-confidence intervall.
You can set the rownames of the result.

```
rownames(Q) <- c("Median", "05%", "95%")
Q
# > Q
#               A    B     C      D
# Median 26.73194  5.5 21.50  9.150
# 05%    18.91642  1.6  4.55  7.645
# 95%    31.14233 21.3 56.30 10.570
```